Why are my star jasmine flowers turning brown
A lot of my star jasmine flowers are turning brown and crispy and dying. It looks like more than should be usual. It’s been particularly sunny so I’ve been watering it every few days. I’m not sure if it’s too much water or not enough or if I need to redo the drainage (not sure how I’d do that). The leaves look healthy on it though. It’s not in a pot. Thank you!

Any chance of a photograph? Is it planted in open ground if its not in a pot?

In my experience this is nothing to worry about.
A sudden colder spell will cause flowers on my Jasmines to go brown.  However, new pure white ones come in a few days as it gets warmer back to the seasonal average.
This has happened at some point every one of the seven summers my Jasmines have been growing.  It only takes a drop from ~20° to ~17° for a day or two to trigger it.

Thanks that’s good to know! There’s a lot though - as many brown as there are white…
